# Evaluate the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{ixe^{-ix}}{((x-3i)(x+3i))^2}\text{d}x$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

I want to evaluate this definite integral without using the error function or any other weird function never used in single variable calculus. Is there a fundamental way to do this? The answer should become a complex number on the form $a+bi$. According to Wolfram Alpha it's $I=0.0130342-0.00749946i.$

$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{ixe^{-ix}}{((x-3i)(x+3i))^2}\text{d}x$$

Would partial fractions be something to suggest here? Or any cleveer substitution?

Comment: Residues theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative view is to unify the denominator product, which is merely $(x^2 + 9)^2$

Once you did this, you can try to choose $z = ix$ $dz = idx$ hence thy integral becomes

$$\int_0^{+i \infty} \frac{ze^{-z}}{(9-z^2)^2} dz$$

If you are not into Residues calculus, life won't be easy, and overall this integral does contain for sure some special function like the Exponential Integral.

For the sake of fun, I checked it with Mathematica, and here is the result:

$$\frac{-3 e^6 \text{Ei}(-3)+3 \text{Ei}(3)-2 e^3+3 i \pi }{36 e^3}$$

Where indeed $Ei$ stands for the exponential integral special function.

In any case, it's numerical so the final value is

$$0.00749946\, +0.0130342 i$$

Where I see an overlap of the Re and Im part.

**EDIT POST CLARIFICATION**

The original integral was

$$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x \sin(x)}{(x^2+9)^2} dx$$

Hence we pass into the complex plane as

$$\Im\ \int \frac{z e^{iz}}{(z^2+9)^2} dz$$

Now it's about applying residues theorem. We see a pole at $z = \pm 3i$ which is double because of the square, so we need the $n$-th order residues poles formula. We will calculate the residue in the upper half plane, following the same integration contour. Thence:

$$\Im\ 2\pi i \text{Res} [f(z), z]$$

that is

$$\Im\ 2\pi i \lim_{z\to +3i} \frac{d}{dz} \left((z - 3i)^2 \frac{z e^{iz}}{(z - 3i)^2(z+3i)^2}\right)$$

$$\Im\ 2\pi i \lim_{z\to +3i} \frac{i e^{i z} \left(z^2+4 i z+3\right)}{(z+3 i)^3}$$

$$ \frac{\pi e^{-3}}{12}$$

As wanted.

The symbol $\Im$ stands for "we take the imaginary part of the integral) because you know that $e^{ix} = i\sin(x) + \cos(x)$ hence we only need the imaginary part here.

Comment: The original integral is actually $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin{x}}{(x^2+9)^2}dx.$$ I just wrote $2x\sin{x}=x(e^{-ix}-e^{ix})$ and somehow tried to move from there. Maybe it's the wrong approach and I'm making the problem harder than it is?

Comment: @Parseval You forgot an $i$, in the sine expansion! In any case if that was your integral then you need residues analysis. I don't know your level of maths, but if that is your integra, then your result is not the above one. This is a pretty trivial integral, and the result is $\frac{\pi}{12 e^3}$ but you need residues. I may write the solution, but... did you face Residues theorem and so on?

Comment: No I did not study complex analysis. I actually never really did any math in university level, just self taught by books I bought. I love math and I like solving a bit more challenging problems. guess I have to learn this theorem then. I've heard of it, but never really used it. I know that the result isn't the same but the first integral is a part, or half of the original integral so I figured if someone could help me solve the first one I could solve the whole thing by myself. But yes, If you have time, I'd love to se a solution to this one.

Comment: @Parseval I edited the answer, adding the Residues way. I really advise you to start complex analysis because it's beautiful and it allows you to calculate A LOT of integrals which are almost impossible to deal with real analysis!

Comment: How did $x\sin{x}=ze^{iz}?$ Thanks buddy, I absolutely will!

Comment: Ah I understand now, you're only working on the imaginary axis?

Comment: When you pass to the complex plane you simply take $x \to z$ in order to evaluate the integral as if it were complex. 

$$e^{iz} = i\sin(z) + \cos(z)$$

That is its imaginary part is the $\sin(z)$ which is what you have in the integral. This is a mathematical trick, basically you decide to evaluate the integral as if it were been $e^{iz}$ but in the end you will take only the imaginary part, because you have the $\sin$. Notice that that the same integral with $\cos$ instead of $\sin$ would give you zero!

Comment: Can you please explain how to proceed with the arithmetic from the first limit with the residue? Only calculating the limit $$\lim_{z\rightarrow 3i}\frac{ie^{iz}(z^2+4iz+3)}{(z+3i)^3} = \frac{e^{-3}}{12},$$ but how did you get the cube in the nominator? And after I multiply $e^{-3}/12$ with $2\pi i$ I get $i\pi/6e^3$, but the $i$ should not be there.

Comment: @Parseval You just substitute!

Comment: @Parseval The $i$ term does not count because as I told you, you have to take the imaginary part, hence it's just the numerical part of the $i$ term! It's like if I told you to take the imaginary part of $4i$, which is $4$, without the $i$.

Comment: Yes, absolutely, I understand! Thanks a lot buddy!